# Code incorrectly determines that a poor fit is a good fit

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, nonlinear-regression, aic

I'm trying to find the best polynomial fit for a set of data. It calculates the AIC for each polynomial fit of a certain degree, and then chooses the one with the lowest AIC. To my knowledge (which I might be wrong about) the lowest value AIC I find is the best fit.

Here, I define my polynomials:

```
def p2(xData,a0,a1,a2):
    return a0 + a1 * xData + a2 * xData**2
def p3(xData,a0,a1,a2,a3):
    return a0 + a1 * xData + a2 * xData**2 + a3 * xData**3
def p4(xData,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4):
    return a0 + a1 * xData + a2 * xData**2 + a3 * xData**3 + a4 * xData**4
```

My function for computing the AIC:

```
def compute_AIC(yData,model,variables):
    residual=yData-model
    SSE=np.sum(residual**2)
    return 2*variables-2*np.log(SSE)
```

And my code for fitting polynomial fits for my data and choosing the best one:

```
def polynom_best_fit(xData,yData):
        print('Assessing if the best fit is higher order..')
        AICS=[]
        for i in [2,3,4]:
            params=[]
            params=poly.polyfit(xData,yData,i)
            print(params)
            if len(params) == 3:
                model_p2=p2(xData,*params)
                AICS.append(compute_AIC(yData,model_p2,3))
            if len(params) == 4:
                model_p3=p3(xData,*params)
                AICS.append(compute_AIC(yData,model_p3,4))
            if len(params) == 5:
                model_p4=p4(xData,*params)
                AICS.append(compute_AIC(yData,model_p4,5))
            else:
                continue
            print(AICS)
            best=np.where(AICS==min(AICS))
            best_model=[]
        for i in best:
            if np.where(AICS==min(AICS))[0][0] == 0:
                print('Second degree best fit')
                print('with AIC =', min(AICS))
                plt.plot(xData,model_p2,color='red')
                plt.scatter(xData,yData)
                plt.show()
                return min(AICS)
            if np.where(AICS==min(AICS))[0][0] == 1:
                print('Third degree best fit')
                print('with AIC =', min(AICS))
                return min(AICS)
            if np.where(AICS==min(AICS))[0][0] == 2:
                print('Fourth degree best fit')
                print('with AIC =', min(AICS))
                return min(AICS)
            else:
                print('Error')
```

However, when I execute this with my code that needs fitting, I get:

[image]

Which has a disarmingly low AIC value.

For a dataset that a piecewise linear regression clearly looked like the best fit to, the function created a polynomial which had a lower AIC value than my piecewise linear regression which had an Rsquared of over 0.99 but a AIC of around 12.

[image]

This doesn't pass sanity checks, so I must have done something wrong here. I think perhaps my definition of my polynomials or the way I defined my function that computes the AIC is wrong, or simply that my understanding of what AIC tells me about the best fit is wrong.

It could also be the case that even though my piecewise regressions tended to have very good Rsquared values, they had an enormous number of parameters (breakpoint 1, breakpoint 2, slope1, slope2, slope3, offset1, offset2, offset3 -- making 8 parameters or variables) which may had made the polynomials win out, but I'm still skeptical that my code is telling the truth.

Comment: Check `compute_AIC`: it's completely wrong.

Comment: In terms of the code itself or how I intended to compute it? Could you explain how to fix this?

Comment: Make the code implement the formula correctly: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Comparison_with_least_squares

Comment: I'm confused - does this mean the proper formula should be `AIC = 2*variables + len(yData) * np.log(SSE)`? I don't know what the constants C1 and C2 mean, and whether I can discount them or not.

Comment: Think about it: the models get worse, in general, as SSE increases.  When that happens, your current formula produces a *lower* AIC.  Thus, your code is trying to select the very worst among your models!  As a general rule, you should not implement statistical procedures unless you are expert at numerical coding and statistics.  Many of us have to do this from time to time, anyway, so it's important during development to have access to a *worked example* where you know the answer.  Get it from a textbook or paper or trusted software.  That will save you lots of time and grief.